# how can use standard twig comment syntax in Atom?

Tags: twig, themes, text-editor, atom-editor, drupal-8

As I asked in above how can I use standard twig comment syntax in Atom text editor?
for twig support in atom I right now use below packages:
[**PHP-twig**](https://atom.io/packages/php-twig) and
[**language-twig**](https://atom.io/packages/language-twig)
But when I press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**/**</kbd> shortcut to puts selected lines in a block-comment, atom sometimes use `<!-- -->` and sometimes use `{# #}` as comment in `html.twig` template files but I want to use standard syntax `{# #}` always instead.
Is there any option or better package for twig language in Atom?

Comment: Seems the problem can only be fixed by submitting an issue to the package github page?

Comment: Thank's for your replay, I find that there is an issue report here for `php-twig`: [Comment Grammar](https://github.com/reesef/php-twig/issues/32)